# pandas: Use unique values in index to group and transpose matrix and fill empty values

Tags: python, pandas

Assume the following import of a dataframe

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

datastring = StringIO("""\
userId  skill  rating
user1   A      1
user1   B      2
user1   C      3
user2   A      3
user2   C      2
user2   D      1
""")
df = pd.read_table(datastring, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
df.sort_values(by='skill', inplace=True)
df.set_index(['skill', 'userId'], inplace=True)
```

This gives me a dataset in this form:

[image: dataset]

I'd like to transform/transpose the dataset such that unique users form a row and unique skills form columns. Whenever a user does not have a particular skill the rating should be set to 0.

The resulting dataset should look like this

```
       A  B  C  D
user1  1  2  3  0
user2  3  0  2  1
```

How can I archive this using the pandas library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) by first level of `MultiIndex` (`0`) with `fill_value` for replace `NaN` to `0`:

```
print (df.unstack(0, fill_value=0)['rating'])

skill   A  B  C  D
userId            
user1   1  2  3  0
user2   3  0  2  1
```

Another similar solution is use [`DataFrame.squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) for convert 1 column `DataFrame` to `Series`:

```
print (df.squeeze().unstack(0, fill_value=0))
skill   A  B  C  D
userId            
user1   1  2  3  0
user2   3  0  2  1
```

---

```
print (df['rating'].unstack(0, fill_value=0))
skill   A  B  C  D
userId            
user1   1  2  3  0
user2   3  0  2  1
```

And last if need remove column name use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
print (df['rating'].unstack(0, fill_value=0).rename_axis(None, axis=1))
        A  B  C  D
userId            
user1   1  2  3  0
user2   3  0  2  1
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort to describe multiple ways how to archive this. It's helpful to get a better insight to the pandas library. I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 2):

Because @jezrael took every other possible answer... I was forced to get creative

***with `set_value`***

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame()
for (j, i), v in df.rating.to_dict().items():
    d1.set_value(i, j, v)

d1.fillna(0).astype(int)

       A  B  C  D
user1  1  2  3  0
user2  3  0  2  1
```

***with `defaultdict`***

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)

for (j, i), v in df.rating.to_dict().items():
    d[j][i] = v

pd.DataFrame(d).fillna(0).astype(int)

       A  B  C  D
user1  1  2  3  0
user2  3  0  2  1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I'll stick with @jezrael's solutions because I think it's better to stay in pandas if possible as this allows pandas to use optimised (internal) code. Your solution breaks out of pandas into python to get back to pandas again which I assume is not as efficient.

Comment: @dotcs please don't pick this answer.  I'd pick @jezrael's answer as well.  I have fun thinking of new ways to do things.  However, `set_value` is very fast and I can optimize this further.  But!, yes, the other answers are faster.  Appreciate the upvote.